# file type and size in php not showing correctly

Tags: php, html

So, the problem lies in my else in my php page, everything seems to work perfectly except the file type and file size.

I have posted the expected result and actual result below as you can see. Problem seems to be it's not catching the type and size properly, and i can't find anything wrong with my code..

Thanks for helping!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <title>2.2.2 Uppladdning av fil</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="default.php">
            <p>
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Sänd fil" name="push_button"/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?php

    if(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")){

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $bild = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $bilden = $bild;
        echo'<img src="'.$bilden.'">';

    }else if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain"){
        $txt = "./uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $open = fopen($txt, "r");
        fclose($openFile);

        echo fread($open, filesize($txt));

        header("Content-Type: text/plain");


    }else {
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        echo "Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        echo "\nType: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
        echo "\nSize: " . $_FILES["file"]["size"] . " Kb";
    }

?>
```

**PHP:**

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Name: fireworks.mp3
Type: audio/mp3
Size: 7881.6875 Kb
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

```
Name: fireworks.mp3
Type: 
Size: 0 Kb
```

Comment: What's displayed if you put `var_dump($_FILES['file'])` in the `else` block?

Comment: `array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "fireworks.mp3"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(1)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: Probably this shows the answer :) - You've got problem with file size.

Comment: @KanchoIliev how's that?

Comment: By refering of Files documentation is seen that error 1 is file size related - UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE. If everithing was right the ['error'] should be 0. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: @Filip looks like you're exceeding the max size for an uploaded file (PHP) - your mp3 file is exceeding the limit and therefore cannot be uploaded. Also, always check that `error` is empty before proceeding with "happy path".

Comment: @Filip also the `elseif` block won't work because you're sending headers after `echo`ing the content. Output must not be sent first: https://3v4l.org/EJgJS

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems is the text/plain header for the else part. That prevent me running this form properly. 
If I remove that, using the following code, everything is fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <title>2.2.2 Uppladdning av fil</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sänd fil" name="push_button"/>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $bild = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $bilden = $bild;
    echo'<img src="'.$bilden.'">';

} elseif ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain") {
    $txt = "./uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $open = fopen($txt, "r");
    fclose($openFile);

    echo fread($open, filesize($txt));

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

} else {
    echo "Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo "\nType: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    echo "\nSize: " . $_FILES["file"]["size"] . " Kb";
}
```

Result I got with a PDF file:
Name: invoice-124927.pdf Type: application/pdf Size: 23609 Kb

Comment: Please notice that I use elseif instead of else if, it's a best practice to avoid else if-s instead of elseif-s.

Comment: This is really weird, it seems to work with all other files except this one... hmm okay, im just gonna leave this problem since it works fine with other files...

Comment: Can you open that file in normal way? Isn't it corrupted?

Comment: @Mcload corrupted for playback or not, a file can be uploaded. He is having an issue with the max upload size limit, which is not the case in your environment and it works fine for you.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic Sure, I have high values set up for post and file upload limits on my mac.

Answer (score -1):

your content type is wrong

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

try with this for audio

```
"Content-Type: audio/mpeg"
```

Comment: I dont want to show the actual content of the file, i just want to show the information about the file

Comment: He is sending `text/plain` for the html content, not for the uploaded file.